# find holes into a dateTime spark RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a question about ordering a DateTime RDD, finding the holes contained in it and fill it, for example, suppose we have this record into my database:

```
20160410,"info1"
20160409,"info2"
20160407,"info3"
20160404,"info4"
```

Basically for my purpose I need also holes, because it will impact over my calculations, so I would like something like this at the end:

```
Some(20160410,"info1")
Some(20160409,"info2")
None
Some(20160407,"info3")
None
None
Some(20160404,"info4")
```

What the best strategy to do that?

This is a little imcomplete excerpt code:

```
 val records = bdao // RDD[(String,List[RecordPO])]
      .findRecords      
      .filter(_.getRecDate >= startDate)
      .filter(_.getRecDate < endDate)
      .keyBy(_.getId)
      .aggregateByKey(List[RecordPO]())((list, value) => value +: list, _ ++ _) 
...
   /* transformations */
...
val finalRecords=.... // RDD[(String,List[Option[RecordPO])]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create dataframe of all dates you want to see in resulting dataset (for example, all dates from `20160404` to `20160410`). Then perform left outer join of this dataset with your `records` and you will get `None` where you expect.